# Memcached CAS with symfony memcached adapter

Tags: php, symfony, memcached

I am trying to figure out how to use CAS feature of memcached from symfony adapter. Theres is many supported operations in memcached such as: "set", "add", "get", "gets", "cas". But symfony adapter interface has only simple methods like set(), save(), get(). Is this methods supporting CAS?

My configuration:

**cache.yaml**

```
framework:
  cache:
    pools:
      memcached_service:
        adapter: cache.adapter.memcached
        provider: '%env(MEMCACHED_SERVER)%'`
```

**services.yaml**

```
Symfony\Contracts\Cache\CacheInterface: '@memcached_service'
```

*Example of using get() method:*

$this->cacheInstance is CacheInterface

```
    public function get(string $cacheKey)
    {
        /** @var ItemInterface $cachedItem */
        $cacheItem = $this->cacheInstance->getItem(
            $this->encodeKey($cacheKey)
        );

        return $cacheItem->isHit() ? $cacheItem->get() : null;
    }
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with CAS specifically, but looking at the [code for the `MemcachedStore` class](https://github.com/symfony/lock/blob/6.3/Store/MemcachedStore.php) it appears that it is implemented internally